# xpath selecting children node of parent that has another node text

Tags: xpath

I have and XML document that contains a very complicated (for me) stricture without newlines
It has a lot of elements with similar structure:

```
<member><name>virtual_size</name><value>117665792</value></member>
```

I need to get the text of node 'value' that is children of node 'member' that also has children 'name' with specific text (in this case virtual_size). Also it is possible that there can be several similar nodes. Can I use [1] etc with it?

```
"//*[text()='virtual_size']"
```

This gets me name node, but how to reach the 'value' one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
//member[name = 'virtual_size']/value
```

finding the member with the name and then its value child

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
(//member[name = 'virtual_size'])[1]/value
```